# Linear algebra on dataframes in Stata vs R/Python

Tags: python, r, stata

In R (and I think Panda in Python), datasets roughly correspond to a list of vectors. Before applying linear algebra on a set of numeric variables in a dataset, one first need to convert them into a matrix (see for instance the code in R lm). This requires a deep copy of these variables, which takes time and memory.

In Stata, a dataset, similarly to panda or R, contains variables of different types. However, one can directly use linear algebra on a subset of the dataset using the Mata function [_st_view](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?mf_st_view). For instance in the  [function cross() documentation](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/m-5cross.pdf), views are enough to construct the cross product of regressor :

```
: M = X = y = .
: st_view(M, ., "mpg weight foreign", 0)
: st_subview(y, M, ., 1)
: st_subview(X, M, ., (2\.))
:
: XX = cross(X,1 , X,1)
: Xy = cross(X,1 , y,0)
: b = invsym(XX)*Xy
```

This seems advantageous in term of speed and memory.

Why is it impossible to do the same in R/Python? Does this difference correspond to important distinctions in term of low level implementation of data structures?  Is there a trade off in allowing such a functionality ?

Comment: Have you read `help mf_st_view`? Differences, advantages, disadvantages, cautions, regarding _views_ and _copies_, in Mata, are there.

Comment: The web link to that help file is http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?mf_st_view, in case Python and R programmers want to take a look. At this point, I really don't get what your question is about. Is it about which software/language to use from the three you list? Is it about the difference between `st_data()` and `st_view`? Or what?

Comment: Just edited. Is it clearer now?  I'd like to understand better why Stata can do it and not other languages.

Comment: It depends on how you store the data. If you are careful, they won't need to be copied.

Comment: I know you didn't mean your example to be serious. For the sake of accuracy, I'll note that `inv(X)` is not a Mata function (there are other inverters in Mata), but it is a Stata matrix function. Even in Stata, the example would fail because `X` will not in general be symmetric.

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced my example by the cross documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know enough about R / [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to provide an authoritative answer but it's likely related to this phrase in your question: "datasets roughly correspond to a list of vectors" (please correct me if the following is wrong).

Program writers always have the choice about whether to implement a data frame as a "matrix" or as a "list of vectors". Stata does the first, and R/Pandas do the second (see link).

To illustrate, the following table shows how each alternative arranges the data in memory (although it's a bit more complex than that). 1 is the first position in memory, 2 is the second, and so on. Also, remember that access is faster if items are contiguous.

Row-Store (Stata):

```
x y z
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Column-Store (R/Py):

```
x y z
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

That has a lot of implications regarding speed later on, and there is no clear winner. For instance, imagine you have an N*K data frame.

If you want to calculate summary statistics of one variable, R/Py should be faster because it only has to sweep through N observations, and they are of the same type which is even better.

On the other hand, if you want to take the average of certain variables, or the inverse of a subset of variables, then Stata is faster because those operations require you to combine access multiple items per row together (I think that's how BLAS/LAPACK work, and everyone basically calls those for matrix operations).

There are other advantages of each. For instance, sorting of one variable should be faster in column-stores (R/Py), but some things that Stata does really well (like those `x[_n-1]` operations) would be much harder to implement on R/Py.

You can see a larger discussion regarding this topic on the database literature. For instance, this seminal paper by Dan Abadie does a great job:

http://db.csail.mit.edu/projects/cstore/abadi-sigmod08.pdf

(although note that some things that he promotes as unique to column stores, such as inlined compression, can be also achievable with a bit more work in row stores; that is the case of the newish strL type that Stata has)